# Putting a graphics card into HP Compaq pro 6300 SFF

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, desktop-computer, overheating, compaq-desktop-computer

I've recently purchased a very cheap HP Compaq Pro 6300 SFF with i5-3470 for daily tasks and I'd like to upgrade it in order to play some games.

PC comes with proprietary cables and power supply, which is only 240W so I am wondering what card could I fit in. From what I've researched it seems that a low profile GTX 1050Ti should work and that PSU should handle hit.

[This article](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3536587/graphics-card-upgrade-compaq-pro-6300-sff.html) says that it should and the only issue could be small form factor which could cause overheating.

Should I be concerned about overheating? If so, what could be some actionables in order to prevent it?

Comment: Does the motherboard have standard atx fittings? It may be easier to rebox it as larger PSU's dont exist for that model.

Comment: It does seem to have an old form factor - Micro BTX. That's what I could find in this [article](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3389530/6300-mobo-type.html)